# Como usar un tooltip sobre una una imagen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Necesito mostrar un tooltip sobre una imagen, he intentado esto con boostrap sin resultados positivos, les dejo mi codigo

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

<div class="container ">
 <center>
<img width="30"  class="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3572978953/8c522d3ea384cd42e46a4a2498300c35_400x400.jpeg" data-toggle="tooltip"  alt="alternative text" title="MENSAJE"/>
  </center>
</div>
```

Mi codigo en [code open](https://codepen.io/KIDRP1/pen/bzXGVv)

Comment: para imagenes debes usar el standar de html que es title

Comment: <img src='https://photos.mandarinoriental.com/is/image/MandarinOriental/paris-2017-home?wid=2880&hei=1280&fmt=jpeg&crop=9,336,2699,1200&anchor=1358,936&qlt=75,0&fit=wrap&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0,0,0,0&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72'  title="Esto es Paris"/>

Comment: si deseas algo parecido deberias ver esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223927/como-hacer-tooltip-responsive-sobre-una-imagen

Comment: eso no se adapta a lo que quiero hacer, quiero el tooltip sobre la imagen no sobre un icono

Comment: En Codepen se ve bien. ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr exactamente?. Necesitas posicionarlo en la parte superior?

Comment: necesito que se adapte automaticamente sobre toda la imagen de la imagen

Comment: Lo siento Jcastillovnz, pero no logro entenderte. ¿A qué te refieres con _"la imagen de la imagen"_? Puedes editar tu pregunta subiendo una imagen que muestre el resultado que deseas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mas o menos te entiendo, esto te puede servir? 
No olvidemos los créditos: @ArnaudBalland

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

*, *:before, *:after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.main-title{
  color: #2d2d2d;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 0.7em 0;
}

.container{
  padding: 1em 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  .container{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
  .container{
    width: 33.33333%;
  }
}

.container .title{
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .content-overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  height: 99%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay{
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-image{
  width: 100%;
}

.content-details {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-details{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-details h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-details p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.fadeIn-bottom{
  top: 80%;
}

.fadeIn-top{
  top: 20%;
}

.fadeIn-left{
  left: 20%;
}

.fadeIn-right{
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="main-title">Simple image overlay hover effects</h1>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">Text fadeIn bottom</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
        <h3 class="content-title">This is a title</h3>
        <p class="content-text">This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">Text fadeIn top</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">Text fadeIn left</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-left">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">Text fadeIn right</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-right">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">Text fadeIn top left</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-top fadeIn-left">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">Text fadeIn top right</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-top fadeIn-right">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">Text fadeIn bottom left</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom fadeIn-left">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">Text fadeIn bottom right</h3>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom fadeIn-right">
        <h3>This is a title</h3>
        <p>This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No olvidemos los créditos: [@ArnaudBalland](https://codepen.io/ArnaudBalland/)

Comment: por el apuro no lo hice, si, ya edito la respuesta (y)